# Different channels in opencv

Tags: opencv, mat

I am quite new to `OpenCV`, I am trying to understand some concepts in it.

I have declared two `Mat` objects `mRgba` and `mRgb`

```
mRgba = new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
mRbg = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mRbg = inputFrame.rgba();

    Log.i(TAG, "mRgba.channels() : " +   mRgba.channels());
    Log.i(TAG, "mRbg.channels() : " +   mRbg.channels());
}
```

I get the ouput of both as four channels. How to get a 3 channel `Mat` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs don't help.

Your assignments turn mRgba and MRgb into exact copies of inputFrame.rgba(), which is why you are not getting the results you want.

How you dump the alpha channel I don't know, I'd just write a loop and do it element by element. Crete mRgb with zeros then assign from mRgba.